# Trying to get Nginx to transform a url ie from example.com/$uri example.com/path/$uri

Tags: nginx, rewrite

when tries to access example.com without the "path" (example.com/path) I meed Nginx to add the path to the url, if it already there then ignore the rewrite. Any assistance would be welcome.

I have tried to return

return 301 $scheme://example.com/path$request_uri;
and it just redirects until the limit of 10 is reached

I have also tried to rewrite but am clearly not getting that right either.

the topology is [proxy] -> [web-server]
I have tried doing the redirect on both, not sure if I should be doing the transformation on the proxy or the web-server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proxy your requests to backend app, you can use

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://upstream/path/;
}
location /path/ {
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
}
```

Rewrite rule is also possible, using [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex, however performance will be somewhat lower than from the first example:

```
rewrite ^((?!/path/).*) /path$1 ...
```